# Скрипт для анализа сжатого библиотекой zlib текста

Tags: python

Всем, доброго дня. 
Нужно написать скрипт для анализа сжатого библиотекой zlib текста.
Пробую написать данный скрипт на pythone выдает вот такую ошибку:

> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Сам код скрипта ниже:\

```
import zlib, gzip
import binascii

original_data = "D:\test.txt"
original_data = original_data.encode('UTF-8')

decompressed = zlib.decompress(original_data)
print (decompressed)
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: @benJAAmen, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

> original_data = "D:\test.txt"

Вы строку с путём к файлу расжимать собрались? `zlib.decompress()` работает не с файлами, а со строками.

Пожалуйста, будьте внимательней при прочтении офф. документации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
В случае со строкой 
original_data = "x.bd``..b. >.....O..{......2426153g......\"N.."
Результат такой же.